# auto height div holder to its content

Tags: css, html

I have a div holder which has a set of divs as children. The issue is that the content is variable by height, depending on the content of its children, so how can i set the css properties for the holder div auto adjust to the sum of heights of its children?

I have tried several configurations of the div holder css like min-height, padding:auto, etc.. but no success.

Here I have placed the code: http://jsfiddle.net/nuAQY/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class called clear, and place it after your last div child but still in the holder.

Like so:

```
.clear { width: 100%; height: 0px; clear: both; display: block; }
```

then...

```
<div class="holder">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
...
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Get rid of your height things in your CSS, too. See: http://jsfiddle.net/nuAQY/1/

Comment: This would not fix it since the divs are not floated.  There's really nothing to clear.

Comment: You're right I was skipping ahead a little in the reading and assumed it would be one of the more common questions people ask, but my solution in the Fiddle still fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the heights on the child `div`s.

When you declare the heights it's saying no matter what the content is it will always be that height, so when the content changes, the height of the child doesn't change, so the height of the holder doesn't change.

```
.holder {
    width:250px;
    min-height:50px;
    border:1px solid #EDEDED;
}

.header {
    width:100%;
}
.body {
    width:100%;
}
.footer {
    width:100%;
}
```

​

Comment: Yes, surely your div will always be the height of the combined heights of your child divs anyway? Am I missing something here? Are they floated or something?

Comment: Hi tedski, the question is that header must no exceed the height set, which is 20px, so if it's not set, it will destroy my estructure. Only the body could have the height not set.

Comment: So just remove the height on the `.body` class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set heights on all DIVs, but the content is more than that height so it runs out of it.  You either have to remove the heights, or set `overflow:auto` for each of those DIVs, but then you will get a scrollbar. If you want to hide the extra content, you can use `overflow: hidden`